# How to call DELETE method in retrofit 2 with params

Tags: android, api, retrofit2

I am calling delete api using retrofit2 it is working in postman properly but giving error in application as below

```
Response{protocol=http/1.0, code=405, message=METHOD NOT ALLOWED, url=http://192.168...
```

here is my base url

```
public static final String BASE_URL = "http://192.168.1.127:3222/";

@DELETE("student/{firstname}/{lastname}")
Call<ResponseBody> deleteStudent(@Path("firstname") String firstname, @Path("lastname") String lastname);
```

and java file i'm calling it like

````
Call<ResponseBody> call = interfaces.deleteStudent(FirstName,LastName);```
````

[image: Postman screenshot here]

Comment: post full error stack please? also show your base url

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6272381/android-httppost-returns-error-method-not-allowed

answer already given here please check .

"405 method not allowed error in android please this keyword to get your answer "

Comment: no it is not reated to my error i,m getting this error in delete api only where my url stays same for all  @YogeshBorhade

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Updated** thanks for your referance @GovindPrajapati
i have to make little changes add **@Field** and it is working for me.

```
@FormUrlEncoded
    @HTTP(method = "DELETE", path = "student",hasBody = true)
    Call<ResponseBody> deleteStudent(@Field("firstname") String firstname, @Field("lastname") String lastname);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may miss the "/" in base URL

**String baseURL= "http//www.example.com/"**

http//www.example.com - This will not work in your case

Comment: no my base url is perfect its working for other get and post api  "http://192.168.1.127:3222/"

Comment: @yuvrajsinh I am not telling your baseURL have issue. you miss the backslash in your baseURL. please read my answer again

Comment: please check in question i have added base url it's with / @RanjithKumar

Answer (score 0):

I think You should set your service url @DELETE("here") like "http.example.com/api/login".

Answer (score 0):

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@HTTP(method = "DELETE", path = "student/{firstname}/{lastname}")
Call<ResponseBody> deleteStudent(@Field("firstname") String firstname, @Field("lastname") String lastname);
```

if above is not working then try this

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@HTTP(method = "DELETE", path = "student/{firstname}/{lastname}",hasBody = true)
Call<ResponseBody> deleteStudent(@Field("firstname") String firstname, @Field("lastname") String lastname);
```

Or you can refer this answer as well 
[How to send a HTTP-delete with a body in retrofit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41509195/how-to-send-a-http-delete-with-a-body-in-retrofit)

Comment: it is helfull bt get error in Path so i have changed it as Field and its working

Answer (score 0):

According to postman `@FormUrlEncoded` method not allowed because data is sent to api in the form of `form-data` so please use

```
@Multipart
@DELETE("/student")
Call<MemberListResponse> deleteStudent(@Part ("firstname") RequestBody first_name,
                                   @Part ("lastname") RequestBody last_name);
```

And here how to get requestBody from String.

```
 String somevalue = "somevalue";
    RequestBody FirstName= RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), somevalue);

String somevalue1 = "somevalue";
    RequestBody LastName= RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), somevalue1);

Call<ResponseBody> call = interfaces.deleteStudent(FirstName,LastName);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, it is working for me:
public static final String BASE_URL = "http://192.168.1.127:3222/";

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@HTTP(method = "DELETE", path = "student", hasBody = true)
fun deleteStudent(
        @Field("firstname") String firstname,
        @Field("lastname") String lastname
): Call<ResponseBody>
```